# Increase spaces between badges in expanded usercard

Tags: feature-request, design, badges, user-card

For the [established user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), in the expanded usercard the spaces between the badges are very less. Could be this increased little more.

**Less space for badges in expanded usercard:**

> [image: Established user]

**Proper spaces between badges in normal user view:**

> [image: Normal user]